# Is there a way to export code to HTML in Eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse, export

I know NetBeans has this feature, but I can't find it in Eclipse. A quick search for plugins was not successful.

Comment: That is a very good question, I have just spent time replacing bits of code with HTML entities, would be good to be able to get eclipse to do this for me....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Java2Html - Eclipse Plugin](http://www.java2html.de/eclipse.html):

> **Convert files:**
>   Select items in the Package Explorer, Navigator or other views and right click to open the context menu. There is a Java2Html menu item that opens the conversion dialog.
>
> **Convert text from a text editor:**
>   Right click on an editor and choose the Java2Html context menu item to convert the current selected text.
>
> **Adjust preferences:**
>   Colors, tab size, etc. for conversion can be adjusted on the preference pages (Menu "Window" - "Preferences" - "Java" - "Java2Html")...

Comment: One big drawback: "Does not use a strict grammar - so automatically generating hyperlinks for navigating source files is not possible."

Answer (score 5):

Hackish way:
On Windows at least, when you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> (Select all), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Copy) what actually gets copied to the clipboard is formatted text (with all the colors and fonts). Then you can paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>) it to something that can accept formatted text, say Microsoft **Word** or even **Wordpad** and save it to whatever format you wish.

Comment: Leading spaces are lost when you paste into WordPress or Blogger. All formatting is lost when you paste into something else. Which formats of the wish are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

> The Copy as HTML eclipse IDE plugin allows us to directly copy our
>   code as HTML and paste it to our blogs or forums without any
>   formatting.
>
> [Download Copy as HTML eclipse plugin [image: Download icon]](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B5oSxq3ttZaEQjA2OXhfMGM1YkE)
>
> Steps to install the plugin:
>
> 1. Download the Copy as HTML eclipse plugin
> 2. Copy it to the 'dropins' folder of your eclipse installation
> 3. If 'dropins' folder is not present then copy it to the 'plugins' folder of your eclipse installation
> 4. Restart eclipse IDE
> 5. That's it
>
> Steps to Use
>
> 1. Select the code or text to be copied
> 2. Select 'Copy as HTML' option or press 'cntrl+shift+3'
> 3. Paste it your superb blog
>
> [image: Copy as HTML]

Taken from here:
http://java-sample-program.blogspot.hu/2012/12/copy-as-html-eclipse-plugin.html